# How to bundle an entire application to run on a HPC cluster?

Tags: gcc, pbs

This question is related to running an application in a cluster, where the operating system and all base libraries are outdated.

The cluster is currently running a CentOS 6 and I have no root access, only user access to the PBS Pro interface.

I have successfully built new versions of many dependencies, as gcc, glibc and others, into a prefix on my home directory. There are other dependencies that cannot be built, I just have access to the shared libraries (for example, OpenCL).

What is the default way to proceed in such case? I am thinking on something like bundling every library into the final binary, but that means that even those shared libraries should be statically linked (including glibc, for example), and I don't know how to do such thing.

Edit:
Forgot to mention that I have tried Gentoo Prefix, but it have failed on stage3, and would like to try GoboLinux Rootless but I can't download it from their website (http://gobolinux.org/?page=rootless). In any case, I'm not sure how those could be bundled to be sent for batch processing on the cluster.

Comment: Not sure if this question is answerable, it is best to avoid what you are doing. After all aren't the admins of the cluster there to provide you with an up to date environment? If the installed version of libc is not compatible with your application you have to provide ld-linux.so as well. See  questions on this site on multiple libc versions on the same system, e.g. [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/1328439).